# Unable to understand the output of program in C

Tags: c, postfix-operator

**EDIT: This question is not duplicate as the behavior is not undefined in this case.**

Why does the below program print the output as 231 in first line?

I have two doubts regarding this:

1. As I am doing postfix increment the value of x shouldn't have been increased before the I call max function. So the output should have been 1 in the first place instead of 2 according to me. What am I missing?

   ```
   #define prn(a) printf("%d",a)
   #define print(a,b,c) prn(a), prn(b), prn(c)
   #define max(a,b)  (a<b)? b:a

   main()
   {
       int x=1, y=1;
       print(max(x++,y),x,y);
       printf("\n");
       print(max(x++,y),x,y);
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   231
   451
   ```
2. The postfix operation occurs after execution of the statement? Consider the example below.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       int x = 0, y = 1;
       int a = x++ /*x is incremented hereafter?*/+ y;             // line 1
       /* Or x is incremented now after execution of above line?*/ // line 2
       int b = 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: 2) Yes, is executes after the statement, or more technically, the statement increments the value and return the value before incrementum, see [cpreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate because my code is just calling a max pre processing directive and not some increments and assignments of the same variable to itself. Please reconsider.

Comment: 1) The macro expansion happens before constructs like `x++` are executed. So firstly the compiler substituted `print(max(x++,y),x,y);` and expands to `prn((x++<y) ? y:x++), prn(x), prn(y)` then to `printf("%d",(x++<y)? y:x++), printf("%d",x), printf("%d",y);`. Then the line get's executed, the first printf prints 2, `x++<y ? y:x++` - the first check returns false, then, the first x++ happens, then the statement returns 2 and increment `x++` again. Then the code prints `3`, as the `x` was incremented twice. The second `print(max...)` does the same.

Comment: @YuHao Can you exaplain why this code is UB? The code expands to `printf("%d",(x++<y)? y:x++), printf("%d",x), printf("%d",y)` and this is not UB,  `?` marks a sequence point, as to [C11 6.5.15p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15p4).

Comment: @KamilCuk for the second question you mean that increment occurs at line 1 right?

Comment: Two increments happen at the first part of line 1.

Comment: Look at the code after expansion. `printf("%d",(x++<y)? y:x++)` will check if `x++<y`, it is false because (x=1, y=1), the it will execute `x++`, ie. `x=2`, because `?` is a sequence point. Then it will evaluate second expression after `:`, ie. `x++` - thus return 2 and increment x=3. Then it will `printf("%d", 2)`. The second `prinf("%d", x)` will print `3`. Maybe see [? operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Comment: @KamilCuk Just to be clear for the second example the value of `x` increments by one after compiler sees `x++` at line 1 itself but uses value of `x = 0` to calculate `a` and adds `y` to it, right?

Comment: @KenWhite There is no undefined behavior here.

Comment: @KenWhite I was not saying it is wrong, maybe you got me wrong. I was asking why is it that way?

Comment: @Michelle this question is not duplicate as the behaviour of preincrement and postincrement with #define  is not mentioned anywhere .U can have a look on my answer

Comment: The `?:` operator has a sequence point, so the first increment of `x` must be completed before the `x++` after the `:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let me take this line

```
               print(max(x++,y),x,y);
```

One important point to note is that the C preprocessor is a macro preprocessor (allows you to define macros) that transforms your program before it is compiled. These transformations can be inclusion of header file, macro expansions etc.

All preprocessing directives begins with a # symbol. For example,

```
                #define PI 3.14
```

tells the compiler to replace the value PI with 3.14 where ever it sees.

```
           c source code->preprocessor->compiler
```

therefore print(max(x++,y),x,y) is expanded in macro to

```
           1.      prn((x++<y) ? y:x++), prn(x), prn(y) 

        2. printf("%d",(x++<y)? y:x++), printf("%d",x), printf("%d",y);.
```

here it gets processed you can check two things carefully here

while checking

```
               x++<y ,the x++ value is 1
```

then after that the x value becomes 2

so 2 is printed

and then while printing also we wrote x++ that means here x++ VALUE IS 2 but

after that x value is 3

so 3 is printed and it follows y as 1

that 's how it works

2.TO give you a great intuition on preincrement and post increment

let me take an example

```
               int x=2;//value of x is 2

               x++;//here x++ value is 2
```

after this line execution x value changed to 3

```
               ++x//here x++ value is 4 and also x value is 4.
```

Comment: Thanxs for the answer. Just to be clear for the code in the second doubt the value of x is incremented at line 1 right?

Comment: NO the value here int a =x++;//value of x++ is 0 so 0 is assigned to a

Comment: @Michelle But the value of x after that line becomes 1 that 's what we say as post increment